# Admob difference between requests from app and impressions

Tags: admob

i made a new admob account five days ago. my app got 80K requests of ads but there is only 1K impressions from admob.my admob ad unit ids are fine they are correct everything in code is working fine but why there is a huge difference and.. dnt know why this is happening can anyone please help?

i tried removing and creating new admob ids

Comment: I'm also having the same problem.